# Access method of outer anonymous class from inner anonymous class

Tags: java, methods, java-8, anonymous-class, method-reference

I instantiate an anonymous class with a method that instantiates another anonymous class, and from this inner anonymous class I want to call a method belonging to the outer anonymous class. To illustrate it, suppose I have this interface:

```
interface ReturnsANumber {
    int getIt();
}
```

And then, somewhere in my code, I do this:

```
    ReturnsANumber v = new ReturnsANumber() {
            int theNumber() {
                return 119;
            }

            public int getIt() {

                // In a modern version of Java, maybe I could do
                //   var a = this;
                // and then call a.theNumber();

                ReturnsANumber w = new ReturnsANumber() {
                        int theNumber() {
                            return 1;
                        }

                        public int getIt() {
                            return this.theNumber();
                        }
                    };

                return w.getIt();
            }
        };
    System.out.println("The number is " + v.getIt());
```

**Question:**
In the innermost method `getIt`, I want to call `theNumber()` belonging to the outermost anonymous class. How can I accomplish that without using the Java 10 *var* feature (as hinted in the code).

**Clarification:** Ideally, the outer anonymous class should not need to know that the inner class wants to call its `theNumber` method. The idea is to come up with some code that lets the inner class unambiguously call *any* method on the outer class.

In other words, how can I make this code display:
`The number is 119`
(instead of displaying `The number is 1`)

**Motivation**:
Someone might ask why I want to do this anyway: I am writing some sort of code generator and want to be sure that the code that I am generating is not ambiguous.

Comment: Many promising answers so far. Most of them seem pretty reasonable given that I didn't give more specifications than this. I will wait a bit more to see what kind of answers come up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Java 8 the solution is pretty easy. Just store the method reference in a variable.

```
ReturnsANumber v = new ReturnsANumber() {
        int theNumber() {
            return 119;
        }

        public int getIt() {

            Supplier<Integer> supplier = this::theNumber;

            ReturnsANumber w = new ReturnsANumber() {
                int theNumber() {
                    return 1;
                }

                public int getIt() {
                    return supplier.get();
                }
            };

            return w.getIt();
        }
    };
```

Storing outer object could also do the trick. But *for inherited methods* only:

```
interface ReturnsANumber {
    int theNumber();
    int getIt();
}

public int getIt() {
    ReturnsANumber outer = this;

    ReturnsANumber w = new ReturnsANumber() {
        public int theNumber() {
            return 1;
        }

        public int getIt() {
            return  outer.theNumber();
        }
     };

     return w.getIt();
 }
```

You can store the method reference or the outer object as a field also.

**Update**

@Holger proposed another workaround. You can pass your *outer* object to a lambda:

```
ReturnsANumber v = new ReturnsANumber() {
    ...
    @Override
    public int getIt() {
        ReturnsANumber w = Optional.of(this).map(outer ->
                new ReturnsANumber() {
                    int theNumber() {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    public int getIt() {
                        return outer.theNumber();
                    }
                }).get();
        return w.getIt();
    }
};
```

Comment: `outer.getIt()` will call `getIt()` it will create a new `w` and then call again `outer.getIt()` , again creates a new `w` - creating endless recursive calls.

Comment: @SomeDude As I mentioned, it will work `for inherited methods only`. Interface `ReturnsANumber` doesn't have such method.

Comment: He might have meant to call outer.theNumber() within the inner class' getIt()

Comment: Starting with Java 10, you can write `var outer = this;`, which allows you to access newly declared members of the anonymous outer class through the variable, not only inherited ones.

Comment: @Holger Yes, I know. But OP mentioned this solution in his question. So I didn't include it to my answer.

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked that. Well, even Java 8 has constructs with such type inference. So you can change the initialization of `w` to `ReturnsANumber w = Optional.of(this).map(outer -> new ReturnsANumber() {   int theNumber() {  return 1;  }   public int getIt() {  return outer.theNumber();  } }).get();` and have it.

Comment: @Holger Thanks! Your solution is very elegant. I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 15):

There is no keyword for accessing the enclosing anonymous class.

But one solution could be proxying the method in the outer anonymous class and making an unqualified reference:

```
ReturnsANumber v = new ReturnsANumber() {


    int theNumber() {
        return 119;
    }

    //Just a different name for theNumber()
    int theNumberProxy() {
        return theNumber();
    }

    public int getIt() {

        ReturnsANumber w = new ReturnsANumber() {
                int theNumber() {
                    return 1;
                }

                public int getIt() {
                    return theNumberProxy(); //calls enclosing class's method
                }
            };

        return w.getIt();
    }
};
```

The need for such manoeuvre should be proof enough that your class structure is not ideal and could be a maintenance trap. You could simply replace the first anonymous class with a nested static class, for example.

Comment: Yes his class design is not ideal and I wonder why would generate code like that. But lets assume one could generate code like that, I am suspecting `theNumberProxy()` would also be available in the class `w` . Then it won't work. It would return `1`.

Comment: @SomeDude That's not true - `theNumberProxy()` is a closure - it doesn't have any reference to the inner class, it can only call `v.theNumber()`. [TIO](https://tio.run/##hVLBToQwED3DV8xNOAjZoyEePGqiMe7ReOjCAF2hJe0U3Bi@HdtlQcDE7aXpzLw38970yFp2KxsUx@xzGLggVDlLEd6QjBL64cXUB1Tw7YM9Ng1U4hgLwmQOFkiP5AK976cV0xqeGRcW5XuNOVQ8BU2M7NVKnkFtc8GeFBfF@wcwVejQVXqbni3cg8BuM0oQWlrPm3g3I405T50hsNvdJe7dO3Yvjp@MJmCQ8TxHhRYpWI2QS7WkcKUr1lclv05baiq5jlZezH0Wk118uUA3@rp/9V1R@KsxGd/9H9C6@WLyta4E4jhlVaUBRVpJbbcC5x3eaKiRSpktG/TJ0oUumjc/ybcFvvPamQ@ZQSAJjtYo1DaxP2nCOpKGosZ@AKpE0E4kjqW3X2gYfgA)

Comment: @Delioth I know , I think you didn't understand what I said, the question specifically said the code is generated. So when you generate code, any instance of an object would get the same set of methods, fields. If `theNumberProxy()` is a method on `v` there would also be a similar method on `w`.

Answer (score 5):

If you can extend the interface:

```
public class Test {

    interface ReturnsANumber {
        int theNumber();
        int getIt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReturnsANumber v = new ReturnsANumber() {

            public int theNumber() {
                return 119;
            }

            public int getIt() {

                final ReturnsANumber that = this;

                // In a modern version of Java, maybe I could do
                //   var a = this;
                // and then call a.theNumber();

                ReturnsANumber w = new ReturnsANumber() {
                    public int theNumber() {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    public int getIt() {
                        return that.theNumber();
                    }
                };

                return w.getIt();
            }
        };

        System.out.println("The number is " + v.getIt());
    }
}
```